# Differentiating between nodes for receiving events in HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I wanted a drop down to implement a particular input. But the inbuilt select didn't look good to me. So instead I tried implementing it with lists. I've had partial success with this. When I click on the text field the list gets presented by sliding down from the text field and when clicking on the list gets dismissed by sliding up. The slide animations are done using jQuery.

On click of any of the `<li>` elements the value gets set in the field. A click anywhere else just dismisses the list.
But now when the list gets presented over a button and when I click on the list, it considers this as a click on the button and just dismisses the list.

How can I tell the browser to take the click on the list instead of taking the click on button when the list is presented?

The screenshot should give a fair idea: Click on all other list items works properly, but ones that's is above the button  doesn't work. In the screenshot, the click on list item Miscellaneous doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event.stoppropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

```
$("#PopuListId").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do rest of the things
});
```

Comment: But I think the hover is recognized before the list click. I've tried this.

Comment: z-index perhaps